# Adding menus in main class derived from QWidget

Tags: c++, qt, menu, qwidget

I'm trying to create a program in Qt that contains menus. The main class is derived from QWidget, and I know I could use QMainWindow to use the function menuBar(), but I can't use layouts in QMainWindow. I tried to add a QMenuBar at the window's layout using setMenuBar, but it does not display like using menuBar() and I don't know how to make it a drop-down menu.

[image: This is the menu added with setMenuBar]

[image: This is the menu added with menuBar()]

Comment: Did you trying looking [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/mainwindows-menus.html)?

Comment: As a matter of fact, you _can_ use layouts in a `QMainWindow`. Just create an empty widget, set it to be the central widget of the main window and assign the layout to this widget. This should work.

Comment: Using `QLayout::setMenuBar()` seems to be working. Show the code you tried.

Answer (score 13):

```
QVBoxLayout *boxLayout = new QVBoxLayout(this); // Main layout of widget

QMenuBar* menuBar = new QMenuBar();
QMenu *fileMenu = new QMenu("File");
menuBar->addMenu(fileMenu);
fileMenu->addAction("Save");
fileMenu->addAction("Exit");

this->layout()->setMenuBar(menuBar);
```

In above code i had used menu bar of widget layout.

Answer (score 3):

You can use layouts in a `QMainWindow`. You need to provide a central widget. Within this widget, you can use a layout like you would in a stand-alone QWidget.

If you don't need the other stuff provided by `QMainWindow` (status and tool bars), you can add a menu by just creating a `QMenuBar` and placing it at the top of a suitable layout, then adding a `QMenu` to it. But I don't know if this works for window managers putting the menu bar outside the window, like OS X and Unity in Ubuntu do.

So `QMainWindow` should be the way to go. Try adding your layout to the `centralWidget()`, not to the main window itself.

Answer (score 2):

You need create a **QMenuBar** object and add it to your layout. Then call **addMenu** function to add menus to your menubar. After adding menus, you can call **addAction** function to add menu items and connect its **triggered** signal to handle user clicks.

I found a detailed tutorial which explains how to do this: [Qt QWidget add menu bar](http://redino.net/blog/2014/05/qt-qwidget-add-menu-bar/)