# How to add a Menubar to a QWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I am currently writing a C++ Application using the Qt framework, in which the 'main window' inherits from the `QWidget` class:

```
class Draughts : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Draughts(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Draughts();

private:
    Ui::Draughts *ui;
};
```

And I attempted to add a simple menu bar to the application, using the following code:

```
Draughts::Draughts(QWidget *parent) :

    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Draughts)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QWidget *menuWidget = new QWidget;

    QMenu *menuGame = new QMenu("Game");
    menuGame->addAction("New");
    menuGame->addAction("Exit");

    QMenu *menuHelp = new QMenu("Help");
    menuHelp->addAction("How to Play...");
    menuHelp->addAction("About");

    //Setup the Application Menu
    QMenuBar mainMenu(this);
    mainMenu.addMenu(menuGame);
    mainMenu.addMenu(menuHelp);
}
```

Should I be using the `QMainWindow` class instead of the `QWidget` class for my application?

Comment: What is your problem? In which way is the code connected to your question?

Comment: found a duplicate: [Adding menus in main class derived from QWidget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684776/adding-menus-in-main-class-derived-from-qwidget)

Comment: Should I rewrite the question in paragraph form? And, whats the reason for the down-vote, besides the duplicate question?

Comment: @edition Not sure why the downvote - not mine. But I would guess you could take some more time to narrow down the problem. And, in fact, you don't really state what's the problem exactly (is there an error? a crash? unexpected result?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be easier to use `QMainWindow`, because it provides a convenient `menuBar()` method:

```
QMenuBar* mainMenu = this->menuBar();
```

But it is possible to add it to `QWidget`, just as any other widget. Just don't allocate it in the local scope, because it will be deleted after the function finishes. Instead, do it like with other widgets:

```
QMenuBar mainMenu = new QMenuBar(this);
```

You should also probably add a layout to your widget, and add the menu to the layout to have more control over where does it appear. You may find [this tutorial](http://redino.net/blog/2014/05/qt-qwidget-add-menu-bar/) useful.